# Button click isnt getting triggered on hitting the enter key

Tags: c#

I am trying to emulate a button click when the enter key is pressed in a text box. I have used this before too but it just doesn't seem to work now.

Please check the code I am using below and let me know if I missed something. I have been away from coding for almost a year now maybe I am missing something?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String uname, password, query;
        int counter = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            verify();          
        }
        private void pass_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                verify();
            }
        }

        private void verify()
        {
            uname = name.Text;  //Initialize variables
            password = pass.Text;

            uname = uname.Trim();   //Sanitize input
            password = password.Trim();

            query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE uname = @uname AND pass = @pass";

            string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.libConnectionString;
            using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", uname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        counter = 1;
                        Variables.username = reader["uname"].ToString();
                        Variables.passw = reader["pass"].ToString();
                        if (reader["regid"].ToString() != null)
                        {
                            Variables.regid = reader["regid"].ToString();
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show(Variables.username + ", you are now logged in!");
                    }

                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid details");
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I am coding in C# in the IDE Visual Studio 2012

Comment: make sure `pass_KeyDown` is set as the OnKeyDown event handler of the text box

Comment: lol thanks @Zruty cant imagine how i forgot all about that :D it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a method with the intention to handle an event, you need to make sure you register the method as a handler to the desired event. If you are not doing so the program will not guess that your method was meant to be an event handler.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
 if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
           login_Click.PerformClick();
        }
```

Comment: I did that @Niang but it wasn't working. Anyways the code works now I had just forgotten to set pass_KeyDown as the event handler for the the OnKeyDown event of the text box